# .NET C#: How to implement role based Login and implement in c# .net Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, role-based

I want to implement a role based login system for my application.
I want to restrict the user to only authorized actions. I want to use [Authorize] tag for my controller actions and i want to create login table in my database using database first approach.

Comment: Functionality you've mentioned is build in default MVC application. Have you try it?

Comment: Show us your effort? Have to even googled?

Comment: Sooo.... What is your question? :) So far you just told a very short story with no ending ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to create and Manage membership based Authentication in C#.net. 
You can use .net In-built Asp.net `Membership Provider` or if you want to build a custom membership provider, it's good idea to derive it from `ExtendedMembershipProvider`. 
For inbuilt .net Membership provider please refer below links:-
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs
 
Or  
    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281573/ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-Provider

If you are using `MVC framwork` then I will suggest you below links :-

[http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates](http://httphttp://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates://)

 also 
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/security/16-adding-security-and-membership

Comment: can u please tell me one thing if i am using server db why app data contain .mdf and .ldf db files in it when i remove it generated again and again i want to use my server db not local db

Answer (score 0):

use Asp. NET memebership manager
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz.aspx

Comment: can u please tell me one thing if i am using server db why app data contain .mdf and .ldf db files in it when i remove it generated again and again i want to use my server db not local db